# Combining Two Unrelated Tables in Power Query and Repeat One Table for Every Row of the Other

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables each comprised of 1 column. Table One [DATES] is a list of ordered months. Table Two [DEPARTMENTS] is a unique list of departments.

I want to combine the two tables, repeating the list of departments for every month in the [DATE] Table

Exmaple:
Table 1 [DATES]:

```
|MONTH     |
|1/31/2022 |
|2/28/2022 |
|3/31/2022 |
```

Table 2 [Departments]

```
|DEPARTMENT|
|A         |
|B         |
|C         |
```

How I want it to look:

```
|MONTH     |DEPARTMENT|
|1/31/2022 |A         |
|1/31/2022 |B         |
|1/31/2022 |C         |
|2/28/2022 |A         |
|2/28/2022 |B         |
|2/28/2022 |C         |
|3/31/2022 |A         |
|3/31/2022 |B         |
|3/31/2022 |C         |
```

I am not sure this is possible as joining requires at the least equivalent type columns to even join on.

Is this Doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Table1, add column .. custom column .. with formula

```
=Table2
```

Then expand rows